# Angular 2 ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'change blur'}"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

I am using `angular 2`, I want to change `ngModel` after Enter press, in angular 1.X we can use `ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'change blur'}"`, but in angular 2 how can we do?

angular 1.x

```
<input class="form-control value-max" type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.filterData.price_max" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'change blur'}">
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? I don't know what `ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'change blur'}"` is supposed to do.

Comment: When you type something in the text field it will not reflect on keypress, it will reflect after ENTER key press or blur. I want same thing in angular 2.

Comment: You can use `(blur)="..."` but that is unrelated to `ngModel`.

Answer (score 8):

As of Angular 5 it is possible!
You can write in your template:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="firstName" [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}">
```

for more see: 
https://next.angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#options

Comment: Was looking all day for this but wasn't sure where to look or what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Angular2 doesn't allow you to modify the behavior of `ngModel` this way.

You can use

```
<input [(ngModel)]="filterData.price_max" 
       (ngModelChange)="doSomething($event)">
```

Comment: that doesnt actually do what dinesh is asking for, plus, the [angular guys say](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14472) to post the request for it here on stackoverflow

Comment: @user292701 you are right. Angular currently doesn't support that. There was a recent update https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/18408 but it's not yet merged.